# JQuery -datatable error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a simple table to which I am applying JQuery datable.I have verified that the number of columns(td) match with the headers. However, I get this javascript error, this is preventing any of the javascript functions from being executed.

```
(function($) {


           $('#myReportsTbl').dataTable({
        aaSorting : [ [ 0, 'asc' ], [ 1, 'asc' ], [ 4, 'asc'], [ 5, 'asc' ] ],
        aoColumnDefs : [ { bSortable : false, aTargets : [2,3,6,7,8] } ],
        bInfo : false,
        bPaginate : false,
        sDom : 't'
});

})(jQuery);
```

In my table , based on certain conditions I added a error row as follows:

```
<tr class="errors-msg">
         <td  colspan="9" class="noBotBorder" style="color:red;">Check this report.</td>
        </tr>
```

Is this colspan creating the problem?

Also one of my td columns is a span as follows:

```
           <td>
               <span>

                  <a id= "approveReport" href="#"> Approve | </a>

           <a id ="rejectReport"  href="#"> Reject</a>

          </span>

      </td>
```

When i look at the javascript console, it reports the following places:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined 
 _fnGatherData  jquery.dataTables.js:669
  (anonymous function) --jquery.dataTables.js:6779
   b.extend.each --jquery.min.js:3
   b.fn.b.each  --jquery.min.js:3
   DataTable  --jquery.dataTables.js:6366
    (anonymous function) -- this corresponds to this line: $('#myReportsTbl').dataTable({
   (anonymous function)-- this corresponds to })(jQuery);
```

Any idea how to fix this, as all the resources I have looked up seem to say that this error occurs when the  != . I have checked and that isnt the case.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure datatable doesn't support colspan, I'm sure it didn't before :

http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/14/datatables-and-colspan

Not sure if that's changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the colspan , got rid of this exception

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I got this error from having badly formatted table HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
<tr>  <!-- PROBLEM HERE -->
```